# use class for element inside div class

Tags: css

Newbie question for CSS.  Sorry if I name things wrong.

I am wrapping tables in `<div>` tag to I can control my CSS/formatting when the information is either in a detail view, edit view or list view.  Everything inside my `<div>` tag with formatting is working fine.  I am not able to figure out how I can reference my css for my `<td>` elements that have a class defined.  For my `<td>` elements I want to format specifically if the `<td>` element contains a label or data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test CSS</title>
<style>
td {
    border:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:25px 26px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:darkgrey;
}
.detail td {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.detail .label td {
    background-color:red;
}
.detail .data td {
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='default' class='detail'>
<table id='detailpanel' cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td class='label'>
Should have Red background but is Yellow
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='data'>
Should have Green background but is Yellow
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Should have Yellow background and is Yellow
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The following does what I am looking for.  I stumbled on CSS selectors that I wasn't aware of before.  I don't know if this is good or bad practice but it allows me to have a standard structure to the tables and wrap with div to apply specific styling.  If there is a better way through CSS, I would appreciate any feedback.

I'm new to this site, so please let me know if there is proper etiquette for apply points or responses to answers given.  They weren't the exact answer I was looking for, but still very helpful in learning and getting to the answer I was looking for.

I am editing my question because the site won't allow me set an answer to my own question for 8 hours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test CSS</title>
<style>
td {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:orangered;
}
td[class=label] {
    background-color:tan;
}
td[class=data] {
    background-color:yellowgreen;
}
.detail {
    background-color:black;
    padding:5px;
}
.detail td {
    background-color:yellow;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.detail td[class=label] {
    background-color:red;
}
.detail td[class=data] {
    background-color:green;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.edit {
    background-color:black;
    padding:25px;
}
.edit td {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.edit td[class=label] {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
.edit td[class=data] {
    background-color:lightsalmon;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td class='label'>
Should have tan background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='data'>
Should have yellowgreen background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Should have orangered background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>

<div id='default' class='detail'>
<table cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td class='label'>
Should have Red background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='data'>
Should have Green background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Should have Yellow background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div id='default' class='edit'>
<table cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td class='label'>
Should have lightgreen background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='data'>
Should have lightsalmon background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Should have lightblue background
</td>
<td>
<br>line<br>line<br>line
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.detail.label` refers to an element with at least the two classes `detail` and `label`: e.g. `class='detail label'`

Comment: `.detail.label` selects an element that has both the class `detail` and the class `label` at the same time – which is not what you have in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`.detail.label` requires an element that looks like:

```
<foo class="detail label">
```

literally an element which has BOTH of those class names set. You have nothing in your html where a single `class="..."` has both of those classnames in it, so of course the rule matches nothing.

You need

```
.detail .label
       ^---note the space
```

So that

```
<div class="detail">
      <td class="label">
```

can match. two SEPARATE elements, each with one of those names.

And note that if the html was reversed:

```
<div class="label">
    <td class="detail">
```

this would NOT match the `.detail .label` rule, because the ordering is reversed.

Comment: Sorry, I am misunderstanding.  I have tried the following, but all my td backgrounds are yellow still.  I edited my sample code above.

Comment: `.detail.label tr td` means "a single element with classes detail AND label, with a descendant tr, with a descendant td". in other words `<div class="label detail">...<tr><td>this will match</td></tr></div>`

Comment: Thank you, that answer makes sense.  I appreciate the quick responses.

Is it possible to structure my CSS to give my desired result using the html structure I am using?